# Question (can we use states(react) in SPFx extensions ? )

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-extensions, react

I have a requirement where i need to :

1. create a button on top header of page using SPFx extension,
2. after clicking on it should open a Panel,
3. inside that panel i want to create things we do in SPFx react webpart(creating
   controls,setting their values create class/functional components) to perform
   further actions.

Can we do that (calling a class component where states are used in extensions) ?

**Please help with some related articles.**

Comment: Check this: [Using React Components In SPFx Extension Application Customizer](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/using-react-components-in-spfx-extension-application-customizer/). let me know if it helps.

Comment: @GaneshSanap :  this is helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use React in SPFx extension, please take a reference of below sample:

- https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-extensions/blob/master/samples/react-aadtokenprovider-bot/README.md

[image]

Comment: this is helpful. Thanks